# vim: FileChangedShell-like notification for file created after editing started

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I really dislike vim taking the focus when I enter a window with a file that has been edited elsewhere, asking me to pick (O)k, (L)oad file and other options.

There is a solution for that: register a callback to the [FileChangedShell autocommand](http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v71/autocmd.html#FileChangedShell) to override the behavior.
I'm doing that, and it works great.

However this doesn't cover a "corner case":

1. create the file in vim, edit it, do not save it (so the file doesn't exist on disk)
2. create the file outside of vim (eg `echo test > fname`)
3. go back in vim
4. trigger `:checktime`
5. instead of triggering the `FileChangedShell` autocommand as I expected, vim bypasses it, and displays a blocking message `Warning: File "x" has been created after editing started [O]K, [L]oad File, (a)nd options:`

Is there a way to override this behavior in the same way that I can override the other related behaviors using `FileChangedShell`?

Comment: what do you mean by: " register a callback to the FileChangedShell autocommand to override the behavior"? i would really like to get rid of this pop up message in gvim but i am having trouble finding a way

Comment: i gave a link to the documentation in my question, that should answer your question, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, as far as I can tell in the vim+neovim source, this would require a patch to add a new feature, it's a separate codepath with no autocommands it would seem:

- [in neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/6130b4a84b41b71f4c0c58093a29585c6c67ff16/src/nvim/fileio.c#L5031)
- [in vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/ebb01bdb273216607f60faddf791a1b378cccfa8/src/fileio.c#L4221)

In both cases this is the next `else if` condition after the case which triggers the autocommands, and that branch does no such thing. So it seems I'm out of luck for now.